# How to write custom splitFunc for bufio.Scaner that scan json objects

Tags: json, go

I have a code like this

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
scanner.Split(splitJSON)

for scanner.Scan() {
    bb := scanner.Bytes()
}
```

I would like to get from Scanner only valid JSON objects one at a time. In some case in Scanner may be bytes that represent struct like this

```
{
    "some_object": "name",
    "some_fileds": {}
}
{
    "some_object": 
}
```

I need only the first part of this

```
{
    "some_object": "name",
    "some_fileds": {}
}
```

For the other, I should wait for the end of JSON object.

I have a function like this, but it's horrible and doesn't work.

```
func splitJSON(
    bb []byte, atEOF bool,
) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    print(string(bb))
    if len(bb) < 10 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    var nested, from, to int
    var end bool

    for i, b := range bb {
        if string(b) == "{" {
            if end {
                to = i

                break
            }

            if nested == 0 {
                from = i
            }

            nested++
        }

        if string(b) == "}" {
            nested--
            if nested == 0 {
                to = i
                end = true
            }
        }
    }

    if atEOF {
        return len(bb), bb, nil
    }

    return len(bb[from:to]), bb[from:to], nil
}
```

UPD
It was decided by this splitFunc

```
func splitJSON(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    reader := bytes.NewReader(data)
    dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)

    var raw json.RawMessage
    if err := dec.Decode(&raw); err != nil {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    return len(raw) + 1, raw, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json.Decoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder) for this. Each [`Decoder.Decode()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode) call will decode the next JSON-encoded value from the input, JSON objects in your case.

If you don't want to decode the JSON objects just need the JSON data (byte slice), use a [`json.RawMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage) to unmarshal into.

For example:

```
func main() {
    reader := strings.NewReader(src)
    dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)

    for {
        var raw json.RawMessage
        if err := dec.Decode(&raw); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf("Error:", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("Next:", string(raw))
    }
}

const src = `{
    "some_object": "name",
    "some_fileds": {}
}
{
    "some_object": "foo"
}`
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/MP-tLr7UoYP)):

```
Next: {
    "some_object": "name",
    "some_fileds": {}
}
Next: {
    "some_object": "foo"
}
```

Comment: Thank you
But it's not the solution. Firstly, and do not know correct structure of coming JSON. Secondly, I don't need path of second JSON, I must wait while it complete and don't get this data from Scanner

Comment: @MarkEaton The presented solution does not depend on the JSON structure. It handles all valid JSON input. If you don't need the second JSON object, then just read one value (call `Decode()` once).

Comment: Thanks so much @icza!
It's really work!
I have updated my question with full solution

Comment: @MarkEaton While it's possible to construct the split function using `json.Decoder`, I suggest to skip using `Scanner` entirely as `json.Decoder` can be used to read successive JSON values as presented.